# How to serialize and deserialize Java 8's java.time types with Gson?

Tags: java, gson, datetime-format, java-8

I'm using GSON to serialise some object graphs to JSON. These objects graphs use the new Java 8 `java.time` entities (`ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, `LocalTime` etc).

I've found a library for Joda Time serialisers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22554290/1212960) - is there an equivalent library for the JDK `java.time` classes?

([This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310143/java-8-localdatetime-deserialized-using-gson) had no luck with their efforts to use GSON with `java.time` - and their question remains unanswered).

Comment: I dont't know if this exactly qualifies as Off-Topic since the OP is looking for an answer to a technical problem. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's a Java 8 library here:

> https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers

Here's the Maven details (check central for the latest version):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fatboyindustrial.gson-javatime-serialisers</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson-javatime-serialisers</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And here's a quick example of how you drive it:

```
Gson gson = Converters.registerOffsetDateTime(new GsonBuilder()).create();
SomeContainerObject original = new SomeContainerObject(OffsetDateTime.now());

String json = gson.toJson(original);
SomeContainerObject reconstituted = gson.fromJson(json, SomeContainerObject.class);
```

Comment: actually it's not work