# Java 8 LocalDate in Grails 3.2 JSON view

Tags: java, json, grails, groovy, gson

When I try to parse a simple domain model object containing a Java 8 LocalDateTime using a [json view](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/single.html#whatsNewJSONViews), I receive a stack overflow exception, that seems to be related to the fact that the GSON implentation does not know about Java 8 LocalDateTime.

Here is an example ([documentation of grails views and JSON](http://views.grails.org/latest/#_introduction)):

Domain class "Person"

```
import java.time.LocalDate
class Person
{
    Sting name
    LocalDate birthDate
}
```

PersonController

```
class PersonController
{
    def index() {
        respond Person.findAll() as List<Person>
    }
}
```

index.gson view

```
@Field List<Person> personList

json tmpl.person(personList)
```

_person.gson template file

```
model 
{
   Person person
}

json g.parse(person)
```

When I try to open this view, a stack overflow exception is thrown:

> Caused by: grails.views.ViewRenderException: Error rendering view:
>   null
>           at grails.views.AbstractWritableScript.writeTo(AbstractWritableScript.groovy:43)
>           at grails.plugin.json.view.api.internal.DefaultGrailsJsonViewHelper$6.writeTo(DefaultGrailsJsonViewHelper.groovy:677)

When I simplify the _person.gson to this:

```
...
json 
{
   name person.name
}
```

Thew view works as expected.

### My question is

Is there a default way to handle Java 8 LocalDate/Time properties in Grails JSON views?
And If not, how can I [register a new GSON builder permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36136066/3244925)

---

- This question is related: [How to serialize and deserialize Java 8's java.time types with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072733/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-java-8s-java-time-types-with-gson)
- I tried to implemented this: https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers but this won't inject itself as new default de/serializer and needs to be used manually

Comment: What version of JSON views are you using? More recent versions add Java 8 date support

Comment: Hello @GraemeRocher, thank you for your feedback. I solved this problem for me, by not using JSON views at all. Sadly. But maybe this thread can be of use for other persons running into this issue. I had the problem above using this maven package: org.grails.plugins:views-json:1.2.0.M2

Comment: You probably needed to add http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails-java8 to your classpath

Comment: Good point. I did not know about this plugin and it was not present as the error above occurred.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

These java 8 date support is not yet implemented in json views. This will work out of the box with views 1.2.0 (when it is released) and the latest version of the grails-java8 plugin at that time.

Edit: To clarify, it is only not supported when using the built in rendering strategy (g.render, hal.render, jsonapi.render, etc). You can still construct the views yourself in any way you want:

```
json {
    someLocalDate LocalDate.now.format(...)
}
```

Edit2: Json views 1.2 has been released along with the grails-java8 plugin (also version 1.2). Java 8 date type rendering is now supported out of the box with the 2 plugins together.

Comment: so does that mean we cant use loacalDateTime in domain classes for rest until then ? i just fell over this in json views 1.1.5 and it made no difference if i had the java8 plugin in or not

Comment: You can still use json views, you will just have to build them yourself instead of relying on the default renderer (g.render).