# Gson deserializing issue for OffsetDateTime

Tags: serialization, gson, datetimeoffset

I am using `gson 2.8` for serialization and deserialization I have `OffsetDateTime` field in my class when I give the value `"orderTime":"2018-05-02T14:23:00Z"` I am getting it as `"2018-05-02T14:23Z"` where I am expecting `"2018-05-02T14:23:00Z"` if I give  `"orderTime":"2018-05-02T14:23:01Z"` I am getting as expected `"2018-05-02T14:23:00Z"`. Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Here is my Order Class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
public class Order {
    @SerializedName("orderId")
    private String orderId = null;

    @SerializedName("orderType")
    private String orderType = null;

    @SerializedName("orderTime")
    private OffsetDateTime orderTime = null;
    ....
}
```

Comment: I don't even see how Gson serializes `OffsetDateTime` to a simple string without something like [gson-javatime-serialisers](https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers) as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072733/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-java-8s-java-time-types-with-gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to fix this issue?

There isn’t any fix. The question is whether there is an issue at all.

`2018-05-02T14:23:00Z` and `2018-05-02T14:23Z` denote the same point in time. When the seconds are 0 as here, they are optional in the format. The format is called ISO 8601. So you have got the value that you expected.

The string you see is produced by `OffsetDateTime.toString()`. There is no way to modify the working of this method (not even by overriding since `OffsetDateTime` is a final class).

There is a fix for seeing another string, though. Use a formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXXXX");
    System.out.println(orderTime.format(formatter));
```

This prints:

> 2018-05-02T14:23:00Z

**Link:** [Wikipedia article on *ISO 8601*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)