# How to deserialize String to java Instant

Tags: java, gson

I have a a JSON string as :

```
{
    "personId": "person1",
    "userId": "user1"
    "details": [
        {
            "homeId": "home1",
            "expireAt": "2023-03-08T15:17:04.506Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

And

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MyResponse {
    private String personId;
    private String userId;
    private List<Details> details;
}
```

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Details {
    private String homeId;
    private Instant expireAt;
}
```

I am trying to deserialize the JSON `String` to `MyResponse` as :

```
Gson().fromJson(string, MyResponse.class)
```

but getting the below expcetion for `expireAt` field:

`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 24 path $.details[0].expireAt`

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Looking at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22310143/6395627), it appears you need to register a "type adapter". This [other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23072733/6395627) links to [a library](https://github.com/gkopff/gson-javatime-serialisers) that may already provide what you need.

Comment: [gson decode instant](https://www.google.com/search?q=gson+decode+instant&rlz=1C5GCEM_enAU1020AU1020&oq=gson+decode+instant&aqs=chrome..69i57.4523j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception you're getting is because the "expireAt" field in the JSON is a string, but in the Details class it's declared as an Instant type. You need to tell Gson how to convert the string to an Instant.

You can create a custom Gson deserializer for the Instant type, like this:

```
public class InstantDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Instant> {
  @Override
  public Instant deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    return Instant.parse(json.getAsString());
  }
}
```

Then, you can register this deserializer with Gson before parsing the JSON string:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Instant.class, new InstantDeserializer())
            .create();
MyResponse response = gson.fromJson(string, MyResponse.class);
```

Comment: You sir, are a life saver ! Can't thank you enough. I have be struggling with from last 4 hours. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Also, thanks for taking the time to explain it so perfectly.